# mvn maven Error: Could not find or load main class #

Tags: java, maven

I get following error with Maven:

```
/home/user# mvn
Error: Could not find or load main class #
```

I have upgraded to jdk7.

Answer (score 0):

Maven opts="xxx had close quote missing.